# Nifi: how to use fileFileter for fetching files from hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, groovy, apache-nifi

I want  to  fetch  files  from  hadoop  directory based  on their  filename,logically  it  looks  like  this ${filename}.* (because  i   have several files  with similar  name   they   look  like this  2011-01-01.1 ,  2011-01-01.2 etc.)  i tried  to  use  listhdfs+fetchhdfs  but   they can't  match my  logic

1. Can   you  give  me any  batter  idea   how  can i  do  it inside   nifi  environment?
2. is  it  possible  to  make   this  task   by  groovy  code inside  ExecuteScript processor ?
3. how can  i  connect  hdfs   directory  by  groovy  code ?
4. after  getting   this  files  i  should   put  them  in   a flowfile list and can't  transfer  flowfiles   untill flowfile list  size  hasn't matched   the   value  of  count   attribute(  placed  in  flowfile)

Answer (score 1):

Salome,

Using ListHDFS can list out every files present in HDFS.

Afterwards you can use **"RouteOnAttribute"** to match files with below pattern then you can fetch those files.

```
${filename:matches('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.\d')}
```

Now it matches with files present in HDFS and it comes in matched route.

Next use FetchFile after RouteOnAttribute to be matched.

Here you can use fetch files with pattern`"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.\d"`

It will fetch your required files only.

Comment: How  can  i  find   how  many  flowfile   with \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.\d this  format  exists?

Comment: for me,  it  is  important  to  check  if  similar  flowfile   numer is  equla  to  count attribute